# How to read the resource file? (google cloud dafaflow)

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

My Dataflow pipeline needs to read a resource file `GeoLite2-City.mmdb`. I added it to my project and ran the pipeline. I confirmed that the project package zip file exists in the staging bucket on GCS.

However, when I try to read the resource file `GeoLite-City.mmdb`, I get a `FileNotFoundException`. How can I fix this? This is my code:

```
String path = myClass.class.getResource("/GeoLite2-City.mmdb").getPath();

File database = new File(path);

try
{

DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build(); //<-this line get a FileNotFoundException

}

catch (IOException e)

{

LOG.info(e.toString());

}
```

My project package zip file is "classes-WOdCPQCHjW-hRNtrfrnZMw.zip"
(it contains class files and `GeoLite2-City.mmdb`)

The path value is "`file:/dataflow/packages/staging/classes-WOdCPQCHjW-hRNtrfrnZMw.zip!/GeoLite2-City.mmdb`", however it cannot be opened.

and This is the options.

```
--runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner 
--project=peak-myproject 
--stagingLocation=gs://mybucket/staging 
--input=gs://mybucket_log/log.68599ca3.gz
```

The Goal is transform the log file on GCS, and insert the transformed data to BigQuery.
When i ran locally, it was success importing to Bigquery.
i think there is a difference local PC and GCE to get the resource path.

Comment: Does this run locally using the DirectPipelineRunner?

Comment: Also can you confirm whether your DatabaseReader class supports files located inside zip archives at all? That's independent on Dataflow - you can just try to create the DatabaseReader in your main program and point it at a local copy of the classes-WOdCPQCHjW-hRNtrfrnZMw.zip file, and check if it works.

Comment: No, The runner is BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner. When i ran locally using the DirectPipelineRunner, it worked well. the path value is locally "/C:/Users/Jennie/workspace/DataflowJavaSDK-master/eclipse/starter/target/classes/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
and this is my option.
[
--runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner
--project=peak-myproject
--stagingLocation=gs://mybucket/staging
--input=gs://mybucket_log/log.68599ca3.gz
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be that `DatabaseReader` does not support paths to resources located inside a .zip or .jar file.

If that's the case, then your program worked with `DirectPipelineRunner` not because it's direct, but because the resource was simply located on the local filesystem rather than within the .zip file (as your comment says, the path was `C:/Users/Jennie/workspace/DataflowJavaSDK-master/eclipse/starter/target/classe‌​s/GeoLite2-City.mmdb`, while in the other case it was `file:/dataflow/packages/staging/classes-WOdCPQCHjW-hRNtrfrnZMw.zip!/GeoLite2-City.mmdb`)

I searched the web for what DatabaseReader class you might be talking about, and seems like it is https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader.java .

In that case, there's a good chance that your code will work with the following minor change:

```
try
{
  InputStream stream = myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
  DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(stream).build();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. i have changed the code your way and i ran it successful. thank you for help.